# LogSuccessfulLogout Listener is not getting triggered when session idle timeout occurs (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

In config/session.php there is key   `'lifetime' => 1` for session idle timeout. After exceeding this time when the user gets log out the Listener `app/Listeners/LogSuccessfulLogout.php` should be triggered. But unfortunately it's not getting triggered. Otherwise if I try to logout manually it works fine.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659998/trigger-function-after-session-timeout-or-expire-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Session expiration after lifetime does not invoke `logout` method of controller.
Servers keep session lifetime and the when a request with old session comes , create new session. So may a session expiration is 12:00.
User has not send request from 11:00.
Then at 14:00 send a request. So at 14:00
User logout. and before that time no operation is done.

I think to accomplish triggering logout listener , you can create scheduled or cron job when user login

Comment: I am using file based session driver..Session are being managed by laravel. Not the server itself. Yea i have already experienced that Auth::logout() is not being called when session time expired. But i want to know what piece of code is logging out the user. And in cron we cannot access sessions.

Comment: There is no logout code. The current session got invalid so the request with this session id can not access to routes under `Authenticate middleware` . You don't need to access session in cron. Just create schedule when a user login in login method . You don't access when user logout but you can handle login

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: No Cron is not my case. Anyways i have managed to tracked the user by creating a cookie var on successful login. so when user gets logout by default it redirects the user to login route, there I destroy the cookie var.